# PL/SQL to subtract two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012, and in my table I have columns `id`, `date`, `days`.

Column `date` is formatted `dd-mm-yyyy`.

I need PL/SQL code to fetch today date and find difference between date column and store it in days column

Example:

fetch today date and find difference of stored date from the table

```
id       date         days
1       01-12-2015      1
2       30-11-2015      2
```

I need PL/SQL code.

Comment: Plsql an MS SQL Server - that's a very odd combination...

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in SQL Server. Do you mean T-SQL? (and this problem wouldn't require PL/SQL in Oracle anyway)

Comment: why are you updating the value in the table itself? without a reference point, you never know which date was used to calculate the value. Or you will have to run this update every day. In which case, just use a view.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2015-06-05','2015-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

For your case it should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (days)
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,table_name.date,GETDATE());
```

[SQL Server Date Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF` and the `LEAD` function to compare against the next row.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d,date,LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY id))
FROM yourtable
```

For comparison against today's date

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d,date,GETDATE())
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: need to fetch stored date from sqlserver and subtract with current date. ---Matt, malyy